In Quarto adjust the transitions for lists
In Quarto I know you can customize how fragments transition, as described in the docs here: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#fragments
But I don't see any way to correspondingly customize the transitions for list elements.
For example I would like all of the following to have the same transition style, which is to initially grow large when the next element is revealed, then shrink while the subsequent element is revealed and grows large.
QMD file:
---
title: "Mathematical Reasoning"
format: 
  revealjs:
    theme: [serif, custom.css]
editor: visual
fontsize: 50pt
incremental: true
scrollable: true
---

:::: {.fragment .big}

::: {.fragment .small}

Test text.

:::

::::


- Item 1
- Item 2

custom.css
.fragment.big 
  {font-size: 50pt; visibility:inherit}.reveal
  
.fragment.big.visible
  {opacity: 1}.reveal
  
.fragment.small
  {opacity: 1; visibility: inherit}.reveal

.fragment.small.visible
  {font-size: 20pt;}.reveal

But as it is now, the unordered list does not grow then shrink.
